# Can't change action of form using jquery

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to change the action of a form and everything works fine, up until changin the action of the form, don't know what's going on? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goToMeetingW() {
jUrl = "https://www.gogoo.com/join/";
$('#meetID').val($('#MeetingID').val());
meetID = $('#meetID').val();
fAction = jUrl + meetID;

$('#goTo').attr("action",fAction);
}
</script>
<form action="test.html" method="post" name="goTo" id="goTo">
<input type="hidden" name="meetID" id="meetID" value="0">
</form>
```

I get an $('#goTo')... undefined error. Thanks all.

Comment: You should use the `var` keyword to declare your variables in the `goToMeetingW` function so they aren't globals.

Comment: Your script works in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VugXW/

Comment: everything looks fine, but doesn't work. You're right about the var thing, i'll take care of that... any other ideas?

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're getting? Or give a link to the page?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything with the ID of "MeetingID".

Comment: I didn't paste that code. Everything works, up until the changing of the action.

Comment: Based on the code you posted, that was the problem. If you would post the rest of the code that might help.

Comment: this doesn't work either

$('#goTo').get[0].setAttribute("action","http://www.google.com");